# How to reference an array inside an object in Powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell, object, collections

To test this code in Powershell, you will first need a firewall rule that is blocking more than one IP Address. Mine looks like this:
[image: Screenshot of an example firewall rule]

The command I'm stuck on is:

```
Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Blocked by Cyberarms Intrusion Detection_BlockAttacker_AllPorts" | Get-NetFirewallAddressFilter | Select RemoteAddress
```

The output for me is:

```
RemoteAddress
-------------
{5.101.64.77, 5.188.206.166, 45.141.87.2, 45.141.87.10...}
```

This seems correct, but I can't figure how to directly reference the array (is that what the curly braces are denoting?) of IP Addresses.

I would like to dump the list to a text file, with one IP on each line, for comparison against other lists.

Comment: `Select-Object -ExpandProperty RemoteAddress`

Comment: Yes, the curly braces in this case are the for-display representation of an array; @Olaf's solution is correct; see the linked question for details and alternatives.

Comment: Note: The accepted answer addresses the dump-to-text-file part of the question, whereas the linked post addresses how to extract just the array of remote addresses from the output of `Get-NetFirewallRule`, which Olaf's comment above succinctly summarizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below script will export your addresses to csv file. This requires PowerShell 5.1+

```
$netFirewallRule = Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Blocked by Cyberarms Intrusion Detection_BlockAttacker_AllPorts"
$netFirewallAddressFilter = $netFirewallRule | Get-NetFirewallAddressFilter
$myFirewallReport = foreach ($address in $netFirewallAddressFilter.RemoteAddress) {
    [PSCustomObject][ordered]@{
        "DisplayName"   = $netFirewallRule.DisplayName
        "RemoteAddress" = $address
    }
}
$myFirewallReport | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation C:\MyFirewallReport.csv
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: As an aside: you never need `[ordered]` for custom-object literals: it is _implied_ when you use `[PSCustomObject] @{ ... }` (syntactic sugar).

Comment: Thanks for the tip mklement0